# Is it possible to remove entire <continent>/<region> entries from tzdb.dat?

Tags: jvm, timezone, iana

I know it is possible to use tzupdater.jar to update a timezone database in the JVM, and I've no doubt that changing daylight savings times (by editing rules in the IANA database) is a fairly easy thing to do.

However, and regardless of whether or not this is a good thing to do in practice, I would like to know if it is possible to omit entire continents or just some / combinations from tzdb.dat.

Can the IANA distribution be edited to do this and, if so, how ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that? I'm not sure if it's possible, but if you could provide more info about what you're trying to do, maybe people can suggest alternatives.

Comment: The IANA database is just text.  The format is well known and documented.  I don't know how to answer your question other than "Yes, use a text editor".